# I want to delete all files and sub-directories beyond a given date from a folder using batch a file?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have used following commands, but it only deletes files and not folders.

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('findstr date: App.config') do set "variable=%%a"

@echo %variable%

for /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('xcopy C:\Users\dsejwani\Desktop\poc* /d:%variable% /S /L /I null') do if exist %%~nxa echo %%~nxa >> FILES_TO_KEEP.TXT

for /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('xcopy C:\Users\dsejwani\Desktop\poc* /S /L /I /EXCLUDE:FILES_TO_KEEP.TXT null') do if exist "%%~pnxa" del "%%~pnxa"
```

Comment: Try this: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-delolder.html

Comment: To delete a folder you'd have to use `del /s` or `rd` command.